# Identifying the Pheasants

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I took a few photos at the Aviary of Hong Kong Park. The photos included some pheasants, and the below shows 4 of them. What species are they? I am not sure if 1, 2, 4 are actually the same species or not. Unfortunately on the official website http://www.lcsd.gov.hk/en/parks/hkp/birds_collection.php they are not included in the bird list, perhaps they are newly introduced.

[image]